# simple regex trouble

Tags: python, regex

my language is python

the input looks something like:

```
'0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0'
```

and so on.

i want the output:

```
('0 0 0 0', '1 0 0 0', '1 1 0 0')
```

or every set of 4 numbers in is its own element

so far i have put together

```
>>> truth = re.compile('(([0-1]\D*?){4})*')
>>> truth.search('0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0').groups()
('0 0 0 0', '0')
```

or and several similar things but nothing is getting closer. a few things here are new to me and i'm reading the docs but can't seem to piece together whats falling apart. Notable i don't now why i get that last 0...

the input will eventually be many many lines but if it works for small case i'm sure it will translate over.

thanks

Comment: Must you do this with a regex? It would probably be simpler if you used `.split()` and `.join()`.

Comment: so many good answers to questions i didn't think to ask.  your all right for pointing out i didn't need to use a regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regular expression for this. Instead use `grouper` from the [recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) on the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> [' '.join(x) for x in grouper(4, truth.split())]
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ALGEI)

---

Here's the source code for `grouper` (copied from the itertools documentation):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very Python savvy, but you could change your regex slightly and use `re.findall()` instead.

```
re.findall('(?:[0-1]\s*){4}', '0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> MyString = '0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0'
>>> [MyString[x:x+7] for x in range(0,len(MyString),8)]
>>> ['0 0 0 0', '1 0 0 0', '1 1 0 0']
```

Comment: Best not to name your variable the same name as the `string` module

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
>>> s='0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0' 
>>> [' '.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(''.join(s.split()))]*4)]
['0 0 0 0', '1 0 0 0', '1 1 0 0']
```

If you want a tuple:

```
>>> tuple(' '.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(''.join(s.split()))]*4))
('0 0 0 0', '1 0 0 0', '1 1 0 0')
```

If you really really want a regex:

```
>>> [x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'(?:\d\s*){4}',s)]
['0 0 0 0', '1 0 0 0', '1 1 0 0']
```

Answer (score 0):

a crazy solution just for fun:

```
import math
s = '0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0'
step = 8
result = [s[0+i*step:step+i*step] for i in xrange(int(math.ceil(float(len(s))/step)))]
print result
```